# How to handle HTTP API request while navigating pages quickly

Tags: flutter, dart, http, flutter-pub

For my scenario, I have used flutter http package to make http requests...In home screen I have to send around 3 http requests, Since I had to use await requests are sending one by one.

I have used BaseAPiService class so all the API calls will go though that,

If I Navigate to another place while above request happening how to destroy that connection? Otherwise if after navigate also app is waiting till previous API requests completed..

Sample base API service class used

```
class ApiService {
  apiGet(url, data) async {
  Get.dialog(LoadingDialog());
  var response;
  if (data == null) {
    response = await http.get(
    baseUrl + url,
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  );
}
Navigator.pop(Get.overlayContext);
return response;
}

apiPost(url, data) async {
  FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(Get.context);
  if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
  currentFocus.unfocus();
  }
  Get.dialog(LoadingDialog());
  var response;
  if (data != null) {
   response = await http.post(baseUrl + url,
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: data);
}
if (data == null) {
  response = await http.post(
    baseUrl + url,
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  );
}
Navigator.pop(Get.overlayContext);
return response;
}
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some code? Hard to tell how to help you.

Comment: sample base api service class added

Comment: Could you also a little bit more specific what  you want to achieve? You want to kill an established connection after switching the screen with the navigator?

Comment: Yes, If I navigate From home page without waiting for the http response, Still code is waiting for the homepage response to complete before sending new http response, I think it's because of await function, I need to kill the connection with http when navigating

Comment: what about `api.client.close();` ?

Comment: Yeah, when researching how to kill http connection, I also come up with that solution. I'll check and give an update, Thank you for guiding me

Comment: client.close() did the work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution

To achieve this need to close the http connection when navigating, for do that need to make a client from http and need to close that client on dispose method

```
var client = http.Client()
var response = await client.get(url)
```

close the connecton when navigating

```
void dispose(){
  super.dispose();
  client.close()
}
```

Comment: That's an excellent solution! No need for a special API...

Answer (score 0):

If you are deep into your code and don't have any handler for `http.Client`. And you don't want the latest response to be shown on the UI. then you can follow this approach.

We cant cancel a future in Dart but we sure can stop listening to a stream. And here is the catch we can convert the Future to a stream and stop listening for it if you want to cancel the Future.

```
void main() {
    // keep a reference to your stream subscription
    StreamSubscription<List> dataSub;

    // convert the Future returned by getData() into a Stream
    dataSub = getData().asStream().listen((List data) {
    updateDisplay(data);
  });

  // user navigated away!
  dataSub.cancel();
}
```

taken for [here](https://dart.academy/how_cancel_future/)